# How to find numbers in a string of a list and replace it with specific character?

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

I have a List of times  in a nested loop. In the list some 'AM' and 'PM' charcters, merged with numbers(Like PM4) in mylist. I want to split the numbers and 'AM','PM' characters and add '-' before numbers. How can i solve the issue?

I have tried to find numbers in string and use the below code:

```
y = ''.join([n for n in mylist if n.isdigit()])
```

then i wanted to use it in an enumeration but i don't know how to use it.

```
mylist = [['x', '5 - 7:30 AM9:30 AM - 1 PM4 PM - 6 PM", "8 - 9:30 AM11:30 AM'],['y', '6 - 7:30 AM 9:30 AM - 1 PM6 PM - 7 PM", "6 - 8:30 AM9:30 AM']]

res= [['x', '5 - 7:30 AM - 9:30 AM - 1 PM - 4 PM - 6 PM", "8 - 9:30 AM - 11:30 AM'],['y', '6 - 7:30 AM 9:30 AM - 1 PM - 6 PM - 7 PM", "6 - 8:30 AM - 9:30 AM']]
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: The title says you want to replace numbers in a string. The body says you want to split on "words" in a string. The code shows finding numbers and discarding everything else. Which of these is your question?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi . The body is true. Just like mylist and res.

Comment: You could try using regular expressions. What you want is to replace any M followed by a number, by ```M - ``` right ?

Answer (score 3):

An approach with [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), can be this:

```
for a in mylist:
    for i,b in enumerate(a):
        a[i] = re.sub(r'(AM|PM)(\d+)',r'\1 - \2',b)
```

also according to  [Sushanth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203743/how-to-find-numbers-in-a-string-of-a-list-and-replace-it-with-specific-character/63203887?noredirect=1#comment111764568_63203887)'s comment you can use list version in one line:

```
[[re.sub("(AM|PM)(\d+)", r"\1 - \2", v) for v in l] for l in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following code with a simple approach:

```
mylist = [['x', '5 - 7:30 AM9:30 AM - 1 PM4 PM - 6 PM", "8 - 9:30 AM11:30 AM'],['y', '6 - 7:30 AM 9:30 AM - 1 PM6 PM - 7 PM", "6 - 8:30 AM9:30 AM']]

res = list()

for i in mylist:
    inner = list()
    for j in i:
        j = j.replace('AM','AM - ')
        j = j.replace('PM','PM - ')
        j = j.strip().strip('-')
        j = j.replace('-  -','-')
        j = j.replace(' - "','"')
        inner.append(j.strip())
    res.append(inner)
print(res)
```

This will give you the desired result.